# Trouble Linking Ruby gem Gibbon with MailChimp API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building a landing page with Ruby on Rails and am using Devise as an authenticator.

I'm using the gem Gibbon to have a user opt in to a mailing list through MailChimp after the user register's through Devise on the landing page. Not exactly sure why I'm receiving the message and where it's coming from.

I've dabbled with the routes and controller a little but no success as of yet. Any in-depth explanation and guidance is greatly appreciated!!!

I'm receiving an Action Controller: Exception caught flag with a NameError in RegistrationsController#create specifically.

```
private
  def subscribe_user_to_mailing_list
    SubscribeUserToMailingListJob.perform_later(self)
  end

end



class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def index
    end

  private
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end



end



class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  after_create :subscribe_user_to_mailing_list

  private
  def subscribe_user_to_mailing_list
    SubscribeUserToMailingListJob.perform_later(self)
  end

end


***TRACE***

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-07 04:51:32 -0700
Processing by LandingController#index as HTML
  Rendering landing/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered landing/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/Blog_Background.jpg"):

actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:21:in `silence'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/logger.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in broadcast'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:21:in `silence'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/logger.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in broadcast'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
Completed 200 OK in 233ms (Views: 205.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: I believe I've added the correct stack trace to the comments above?? Not sure on where to start on reading a trace to troubleshoot